# C program to convert the row and column containing a 0 value to zero

Tags: c, matrix

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
{
int mat[3][3]={{0,2,3},{4,9,5},{0,1,8}};
int i,j,c;
int x=0;


for(i=0;i<3;i++)
for(j=0;j<3;j++)
if(mat[i][j]==0)
c++;
int col[c],row[c];
x=0;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{for(j=0;j<3;j++,x++)
{
    if(mat[i][j]==0)
    {
        col[x]=j;
        row[x]=i;
    }
}}
for(x=0;x<c;x++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        mat[row[x]][j]=0;mat[j][col[x]]=0;
    }
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

What i am doing inthe above code is that i am storing the positions where a zero is present and storing it in an array.
Now i am using these positions to change the row and column of the zero value to zero. 
While executing i am getting an segmentation fault.Can someone pin-point my mistake.

Comment: what did the debugger say?

Comment: First, initialize `c` and then increment it.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in response to comments. It makes comments and answers hard to follow.

Comment: Rolled back to remove the mods suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the uninitilialised `c` used to define array sizes, you need to increment `x` after each pair of indices is stored. Take `,x++` out of the `for` loop statement, it's wrong just there (since you might not find a `0` value).

Because of this, `x` is incremented whether or not you write index values to the arrays. In the case where you don't, these array elements of `col[]` and `row[]` are uninitiliased. So when you use them later to index, you get Undefined Behaviour from using uninitialised values which very likely fall outside of the array they are indexing.

Remember: you have to specifically initialise all local variables.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to initialize c to 0

> ```
> int i,j,c=0;
> ```

2. Increment x only when a 0 is found

> ```
> for(j=0;j<3;j++)
> {
> if(mat[i][j]==0)
> {
>     col[x]=j;
>     row[x]=i;
>     x++;
> }
> }
> ```

3. int main() is missing

While this is not the most efficient solution, the above changes shall perform the required task.